# Indexed records are getting deleted in solr. What could be the reason?

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene, solr7

Indexed records are getting deleted in Solr 7.7.2 version. This is happening only in 1 instance.
There is no specific pattern when it is getting deleted. In 18000 records, sometimes around 2000 or 8000 are remaining after deletion. Physical memory is 95% used. No out of memory error.
No programmatical scheduler or activity is happening during this deletion. Please suggest

I tried re-indexing multiple times, but again getting deleted at unknown time. Sometimes it is 1 day, sometimes it is 3 days or more and no specific pattern.
Tried checking logs, nothing found suspicious (no memory error)

Comment: If you turn logging up to INFO Solr will log every request issued and the result of that request; compare that request log to when the records disappear.